# Replicating rows from DGV into the list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, datagridview

This way I'm accessing as a list from my datagridview. The problem I'm facing here..Lets say if i have `6 rows` in the DGV, when it updates to the list it shows `36rows`. 
How can i fix this problem??

```
for (int i = 0; i < testDsrcConfigs .Count; i++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(testDsrcConfigs [i]);
            }
```

From the for loop, i can see 6 rows. 
Is it possible to use `for loop`?? How can i adapt fro loop to access the members??Please help me..!

```
List<SdrcConfig> testDsrcConfigs = new List<SdrcConfig>();


foreach (GridViewRowInfo dr in RadGridView.Rows)
    {
        //Create a TrafficLane list 
        List<TrafficLane> covTrafLane = new List<TrafficLane>();

        if (dr.Cells["bct0"].Value != "XXXX")
            {
                covTrafLane.Add(new TrafficLane(dr.Cells["bct0"].Value.ToString()));
            }
        if (dr.Cells["bct1"].Value != "XXXX")
            {
                covTrafLane.Add(new TrafficLane(dr.Cells["bct1"].Value.ToString()));
            }
        if (dr.Cells["bct2"].Value != "XXXX")
            {
                covTrafLane.Add(new TrafficLane(dr.Cells["bct2"].Value.ToString()));
            }
        if (dr.Cells["bct3"].Value != "XXXX")
            {
                covTrafLane.Add(new TrafficLane(dr.Cells["bct3"].Value.ToString()));
            }

            //Create RseDevicePosition
            DevicePosition devPos;
            int ctx;
            Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["bx"].Value.ToString(), out ctx);
            int cty;
            Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["by"].Value.ToString(), out cty);
            int ctz;
            Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["bz"].Value.ToString(), out ctz);
            int bazu;
            Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["bazim"].Value.ToString(), out bazu);
            int bele;
            Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["belev"].Value.ToString(), out bele);
            int bti;
            Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["btilt"].Value.ToString(), out bti);


            ushort devnum = UInt16.Parse(dr.Cells["bdevnum"].Value.ToString());

            devPos = new DevicePosition(
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(ctx, "mm"),
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(cty, "mm"),
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(ctz, "mm"),
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(bazu, "tenthOfDegree"),
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(bele, "tenthOfDegree"),
                new ValueWithUnit<int>(bti, "tenthOfDegree"));


            ((MyConfig.
            .ObuTransactionSystemConfig as DsrcTransactionSystemConfig).
                 DsrcSystemConfig as MultiLaneDsrcSystemConfig).DsrcConfigs.ForEach(
                     dsrcBeacon => testDsrcConfigs.Add(
                         new SdrcConfig(
                             dr.Cells["bid"].Value.ToString(), 
                             dr.Cells["bdesc"].Value.ToString(),        
                             covTrafLane,
                             devPos, devnum,
                             dsrcBeacon.Settings)));
    }
```

Comment: My initial guess would be the .ForEach(dsrcBeacon... wrapped in the the outer foreach (GridViewRowInfo dr in RadGridView.Rows). I bet if you add another row to the DGV (making 7 total) you'll have 49 after the update.

Comment: @ KreepN: Please tell me what is the mistake?? and what should i do??

Comment: Is your concern the fact that you have to many entries in your list or are you having issues with the for loop?

Comment: @ KreepN: If i have 6 rows in the DGV, when i take the list, i should have only 6. My first concern is how cna i fix this problem with for loop?? or What is the best possible solution?? Thank you

Comment: If you wish to access the members why not try a simple var a = testDsrcConfigs [i]; and step through the loops to see what a is equal to.

Comment: Nope, i'm sorry, this way too i have the same problem? It's showing 36 rows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18881/discussion-between-kreepn-and-linguini)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following change:

```
((MyConfig.
        .ObuTransactionSystemConfig as DsrcTransactionSystemConfig).
             DsrcSystemConfig as MultiLaneDsrcSystemConfig).DsrcConfigs.ForEach(
                 dsrcBeacon => testDsrcConfigs.Add(
                     new SdrcConfig(
                         dr.Cells["bid"].Value.ToString(), 
                         dr.Cells["bdesc"].Value.ToString(),        
                         covTrafLane,
                         devPos, devnum,
                         dsrcBeacon.Settings)));
```

to

```
testDsrcConfigs.Add(
                     new SdrcConfig(
                         dr.Cells["bid"].Value.ToString(), 
                         dr.Cells["bdesc"].Value.ToString(),        
                         covTrafLane,
                         devPos, devnum,
                         ((MyConfig.
    .ObuTransactionSystemConfig as DsrcTransactionSystemConfig).
         DsrcSystemConfig as MultiLaneDsrcSystemConfig).DsrcConfigs[0].Settings);
```